# Particle distribution and material looks different in viewport compared to render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view, particles

I'm working on a project with a long row of buildings. The buildings are distributed with a hair particle system on an array of planes. All the buildings are one material, with an object info node plugged into a noise texture going into a constant color ramp to determine the color of the buildings.

[image: buildingcolor]

However, the buildings look like this in the viewport:

[image: buildings1]

And like this in the render:

[image: buildings2]

Not only are the colors different, but so are the building types. There aren't any children in the particle system.
This is my modifier stack for the particle system:

[image: modifierstack]

How do I fix this? Is this an inherent property of the particle system, or am I messing something up? Do I have to use something like geometry nodes? Thanks!

UPDATE: I seemed to have fixed it, kind of. This is my outliner:

[image: outliner]

I tried a lot of random things, but it seems that checking the collection group and then unchecking it fixed the issue (I tried other things like making the collection viewable or hidden in the render, both of which changed the render house order/color). However, the colors are now completely different, but at least they are synched between the viewport and render.

Blend-Exchange seems to be down: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1icrzSHqaWQJxqwB28QpAagWLL4cbvj69/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have any modifiers or settings where they have different values for Viewport and Render?

Comment: @Kuboå Nope, I just checked. I also don't think that this is a result of a modifier, I'm not sure how a modifier would change the building type and color.

Comment: If you have a Subdivision Surface modifier with differing Viewport/Render values on a mesh you have a particle system on, for instance, you'd get different amount of faces, which means different indices and different distribution/instancing results.

Comment: @Kuboå I do have a subsurf modifier on the particle system mesh, but the values for viewport and render are the same. Even when I turn off the subsurf modifier, the same thing happens.

Comment: Originally, I had all the buildings in separate collections, all disabled. I enabled the buildings, and had to set them to enabled in renders as well. I moved the buildings out of frame (so there's a clump of intersecting buildings off-camera), and the buildings are now correct in the render. However, the material is still incorrect. Really unsure about what's going on.

Comment: And now if I don't show the DISABLED collection in the render, it doesn't render the houses anymore?!? And the materials match up now somehow, even though all I've done is uncheck a box on and off.

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out. But i would agree with Kuboa - you have made something different for render + viewport

Comment: You need to disable the library collection for render, not the individual objects inside it. Please post a screenshot of your outliner

Comment: @Chris I've been trying to, but blend-exchange keeps saying that "there was an internal error attempting to complete your request."

Comment: @EdwardWang: i know - it seems to have problems. just use another cloud service like dropbox or whatever

Comment: @Chris updated post and also added file link